# How to calculate monthly instalment specifed in task in maxima?

Tags: task, maxima, wxmaxima, annuity

I am stuck trying to make a solution for a task my tutor asked me to do using `wxMaxima`.

Here's the task:
"On `June 1`, you take a mortgage that is repaid in fixed monthly instalments for 10 years at the end of each
month (we assume that there are `12` equal months in a year). The loan amount is `130 000`.

The
loan interest rate is variable, i.e. the bank changes it every set interval. Please calculate the amount of the fixed loan instalment (as described above).

Then, assuming that on the first day of March, your bank decreases the interest rate on your loan by `2` percentage points.

Please calculate the new instalment. The current interest rate should be `9.49%` and assumed as capitalised annually.
Also I have some formulas for annuity:

```
AIFV(A,r,t,m):=A*sum((1+r/m)^i,i,0,t*m-1);
AIPV(A,r,t,m):=A*sum((1+r/m)^(-i),i,1,t*m);
ADFV(A,r,t,m):=A*sum((1+r/m)^i,i,1,t*m);
ADPV(A,r,t,m):=A*sum((1+r/m)^(-i),i,0,t*m-1);,
```

where A is installment, `r` is interest rate, `t` is years and `m` is how often it is capitalized.

I've tried to do it, but I don't know how to handle the change in interest rate in next periods.

I've made a file in Excel calculating this, but my tutor said that excel is not enough and I need to do it in `wxMaxima`.

Can anyone help or just give me a hint?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I haven't looked closely at this, but one idea is that you could make the interest rate a function of the month by representing it as a subscripted variable `r[i]` instead of a simple number. Then you can create a list `r: [949/10000, 849/10000, 749/10000, ...]` (the values are just place holders, you can put whatever is appropriate there). One way to debug Maxima code is to postpone substitution for numerical values as long as possible. For example, if you evaluate `AIFV(A, r, r, 24)` you should get an explicit sum of 24 terms. You can verify the terms are correct before substituting numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've decided to do it manually — calculating principal installment and interest installment for every month till March and then using current loan amount and function AIPV.